# Singular value decomposition: why the reconstructed matrix has totally different range of values than the original matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, svd

I decompose using SVD a sparse matrix R into U, Sigma and Vt. I use k = 20 terms. The original matrix is of shape: 98720 x 24875 and has only values of 0 and 1.

> (np.min(R) = 0, np.max(R) =  1, np.mean(R) = 0.0003790496241336341,

> <98720x24875 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
> with 930817 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
> scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix)

The reconstructed the matrix: `R_reconstructed =  np.dot(np.dot(U, np.diag(sigma)), Vt)` has values in a different range (-1,5, 3.82).

> (98720, 24875) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> -1.5699363645844981 3.821880643066242

Can someone explain me why is the case and what is the solution in order to obtain the same range for the reconstructed matrix ?

Comment: can you reduce `np.dot(np.dot(U, np.diag(sigma)), Vt)` to  `np.dot(U * sigma, Vt)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that because k is small, the reconstruction is not perfect. You maybe need to use a larger k until at least you have a similar mean because the extreme values are difficult to reproduce with SVD until you use a large k.

To make an example:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

m = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.poisson(0.1, (1000, 200)).astype("float"))
m.max(), m.min(), m.mean()
```

max is 4, min is 0., mean is 0.1

If I reconstruct with k=20

```
k = 20
u, s, vh = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(m, k=k, which="LM")
m_r = np.dot(u, np.dot(np.diag(s), vh))
m_r.max(), m_r.min(), m_r.mean()
```

max is 1.5, min is -0.6 mean is 0.0995

If I reconstruct with k=100 max is 3.33 min is -0.58 mean is 0.0996

If I reconstruct with k=199 max is 4.001, min is -0.13 mean is 0.0997